# Can font faces be dynamically assigned with font-lock-add-keywords?

Tags: faces, font-lock, variables

In all the examples of `font-lock-add-keywords` I've seen, the font face is static.

That is, there is a regex or a matcher function and a literal font face identifier.

Is it possible to set the face dynamically? So the font face used can be selected using code that interacts with the matches for example?

Otherwise I would have to register multiple matchers, one for each face used.

Comment: *"font face"* isn't a clear term, to me. I think you just mean *face*, or maybe just *font* (one face attribute). Please clarify what you mean for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. See the Elisp manual, node [Search-based Fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html).

`font-lock-keywords` (which you set using `font-lock-keywords`, e.g. `font-lock-add-keywords`) can use a `FACESPEC` expression, which is *evaluated* to provide the face to use.

> `FACESPEC` is an expression whose value
> specifies the face to use for highlighting.  In the simplest case,
> `FACESPEC` is a Lisp variable (a symbol) whose value is a face name.
>
> ```
> ;; Highlight occurrences of ‘fubar’,
> ;; using the face which is the value of ‘fubar-face’.
> ("fubar" . fubar-face)
> ```
>
> However, `FACESPEC` can also evaluate to a list of this form:
>
> ```
> (face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2...)
> ```
>
> to specify the face `FACE` and various additional text properties to
> put on the text that matches.  If you do this, be sure to add the
> other text property names that you set in this way to the value of
> `font-lock-extra-managed-props` so that the properties will also be
> cleared out when they are no longer appropriate.  Alternatively,
> you can set the variable `font-lock-unfontify-region-function` to a
> function that clears these properties.  *Note Other Font Lock Variables::.